# plotting the old data(for an earlier plot) again while making a new plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have CSV file with entries like following

```
id, A, B    #first line.
1, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8(and many more), 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2(and many more) #line 1
...
...
(many more lines like this)
```

Here is the script to plot the graph each line and save it to file. For example the pairs to be plotted will be {1,0};{2,9};{3,8};...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

def plot( fileName, x, y):
    fileNameWithExt=fileName
    fileNameWithExt+='.png'
    print fileNameWithExt
    plt.plot( x, y )
    plt.xlabel( "X values" )
    plt.ylabel( "Y values" )
    plt.savefig(fileNameWithExt)

if __name__=="__main__":
    with open('test', 'r')  as csvfile:
        next(csvfile)
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in spamreader:
            print (row[1].strip()).split(" ")
            x = map(int, (row[1].strip()).split(" "))
            y = map(int, (row[2].strip()).split(" "))
            plot(row[0], x, y)
```

The example file(`test`) is as follows:

```
id, A, B
train1, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, 2 9 8 7 6 5 4 3
train2, 8 5 6 9 3 2 0 1, 2 4 6 8 6 9 1 6
```

[image: train1.png]
[image: train2.png]

As one would see, the second plot contains value from the first plot too. I do not understand why this is happening even I have deleted the list after plotting. What mistake I am making.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Either make a new figure or clear the old one. By default, matplotlib assumes you want to plot on the same figure (e.g. `hold=True`). Add a `plt.clf()` before your plotting call.

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks. It worked. Could you please write that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close or clear the plot between loops:

eg. `plt.close()`

`cla()` clears an axis, i.e. the currently active axis in the current figure. It leaves the other axes untouched.

`clf()` clears the entire current figure with all its axes, but leaves the window opened, such that it may be reused for other plots.

`close()` closes a window, which will be the current window, if not specified otherwise.